# iOS - White Corners on Views

Tags: ios, uiview

Some of my Views seem to have white corners on the Navigation Bar, mostly those who are modally presented - I am wondering, how can I make those disappear?

[image]

Comment: That's a custom nav bar. Do you have access to it's source code?

Comment: Likely a custom background image.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating your views and your navigation bars?

Typically you have to set clipsToBounds on a view so that it doesn't draw outside it's bounds, and set masksToBounds on the view's layer so that it doesn't draw outside its masked area.

I haven't had to do that with navigation bars however, so I'm not sure what's going on with your app. (Then again, I haven't been writing iOS 7 native apps for very long, and the behavior of navigation bars and status bars changed radically with iOS 7.)

Post your code that sets up your view controller and configures your navigation bar.

Comment: The NavBar is being created on the StoryBoards by dragging it into the view - To cover up the StatusBar, we use a 20points high UIView.  In This case tough, the NavBar is coming directly from the NavigationController.